# Accessing bot from my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework

I have a quick question here about using bots on Facebook page?

I have created a sample bot. My bot is registered at Microsoft Bot Framework and I have successfully configured and tested my bot for Facebook.

But when I login from my test Facebook account and send a message to my page I am not able to get back the automated bot reply. Is there any additional setting for this?

Comment: Is the bot deployed to azure or are using ngrok?

Comment: Azure .........

Comment: Note: I am not using a device. I am trying messenger web application https://www.messenger.com

Comment: When you say you've "tested your bot for Facebook" you mean is has replied to one of your posts?

Comment: Yes, from the same fb account the bot is connected with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until your bot has been [submitted and approved by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review) it will only respond to the owners of the Facebook page, individuals who have been given the "Testers" role or Test Users that you have created. ([More info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)).  Look at the "Roles" section on your dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Just want to add that Test Users generated by Facebook don't seem to work with the bot. Tried many times but no success. Only real users that were granted either the Admin or Tester or another role.

Comment: @Lars: That worked. Just wanted to know where can I check the status of my bot (Facebook app) status with the Facebook if it has been approved?